# How to setup relationship between 2 table which has both one-to-many and many-to-many relationship?

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a Users table and an Events table.

It's has one-to-many relationship.

Each **user** can create many **event**.

Each **event** belongs to one **user**.

Also, it has many-to-many relationship.

Each **user** can join as many **event** as they want.

Each **event** can be joined by many **user**.

This needs pivot table.

Now, I'm stuck.

This is event model.

```php
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function users(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                 ->withTimestamps();
}
```

This is user model.

```php
public function events(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}

public function events(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
}
```

The problem is in the user model where I can't define multiple function with the same name.

So, is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: show your events and users table as well

Comment: I don't get this sentence of yours "The problem is in the user model where I can't define multiple function with the same name.

" explain please

Comment: Your relationships are correct. Just use a different name for one of the `events` relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick answer

Of course you can't have two functions with the same name. In your case, try to use more specific names for each function:

```php
public function createdEvents()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}

public function joinedEvents()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
}
```

## Recommendation

You can use a single `many-to-many` relationship to manage both relations with [Pivot information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

**`users` table**

- `id`
- `username`
- ...

**`events` table**

- `id`
- `name`
- ...

**`event_user` table**

- `user_id`
- `event_id`
- `is_creator` (default `FALSE`, unsigned integer)
- ...

Then when creating an event, relate the `user` and `event` objects and set the `is_creator` field to `TRUE`.

So in your `User` model:

**app/User.php**

```php
public function events()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')->withPivot('is_creator');
}
```

Then in your controller when you want to create an event:

**app/Http/Controllers/SomeCoolController.php**

```php
public function store(CreateEventRequest $request)
{
    // Get your event data
    $data = $request->only(['your', 'event', 'fields']);
    // create your object
    $newEvent = Event::create($data);
    // create the relationship with the additional pivot flag.
    auth()->user()->events()->attach($newEvent, ['is_creator' => true]);

    // the rest of your code.
}
```

And when a user want to 'join' an event:

**app/Http/Controllers/SomeCoolController.php**

```php
public function join(JoinEventRequest $request)
{
    // Get the event
    $event = Event::find($request->event_id);
    // relate the ev
    auth()->user()->events()->attach($newEvent, ['is_creator' => false]);
    // or just this, because its already set to false by default:
    // auth()->user()->events()->attach($newEvent);

    // the rest of your code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's many to many relationships between `User` and `Event` so there will be pivot name like `user_event`

user model

```
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')->using('App\UserEvent'); 
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many